# Al solicitar un dato desde firestore puedo imprimirlo con console.log pero al guardarlo en una variable me devuelve undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, promesas, undefined

He estado teniendo un problemas al solicitar datos desde mi base de datos en firestore, y sucede lo siguiente:

He creado mi variable `datoGrafico` donde pretendo guardar el dato que estoy llamando desde mi firestore. He guardado el dato que deseo obtener en la variable `valor1`, y al imprimir `console.log(valor1)` me imprime en la consola el dato que estoy solicitando.

Sin embargo, al poner `return valor1` para que mi variable `datoGrafico` devuelva este valor, esto lo que hace es entregarme `undefined`. Lo único que busco es guardar los datos de mi firestore en variables de la forma más simple posible, para así usar estas variables para construir gráficos y cosas así. Espero se haya entendido bien mi pregunta, gracias !

```
let datoGrafico = async function() {
    let {currentUser : user} = await firebase.auth();
    if (user != null) {
      var uid = user.uid;
    }
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    var docRef = await db.collection("infoUsuarios").doc(uid)
    docRef.onSnapshot(function(doc) {
      if (doc && doc.exists) {
        let valor1 = doc.data().Peso;
        console.log(valor1) //aqui logro imprimir el valor que quiero
        return valor1;
      }else{
        console.log("no dato");
      }
    }
    );
  }

console.log(datoGrafico()) //pero aqui me devuelve una promesa pendiente

datoGrafico().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result)  //y aqui me devuelve undefined
 })
```

Comment: Por lo pronto no veo por ningún lado que devuelvas una promesa que devuelva algo. ¿Es `valor1` lo que quieres obtener cuando se revuelva la promesa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para que `then()` te proporcione el dato que estás esperando tienes que hacer una de dos cosas:

- Devolver una promesa que resuelva con el valor que deseas.
- Devolver la promesa de la consulta a la base de datos.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacer lo primero:

```
/* En este caso crearemos una promesa */
let datoGrafico = async function() {
    return new Promise(resolver => {
        let {currentUser : user} = await firebase.auth();
        if (user != null) {
            var uid = user.uid;
        }
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        var docRef = await db.collection("infoUsuarios").doc(uid)
        docRef.onSnapshot(doc => {
            if (doc && doc.exists) {
                let valor1 = doc.data().Peso;
                console.log(valor1); //aqui logro imprimir el valor que quiero
                /* Aquí devolvemos el resultado de la promesa */
                resolver(valor1);
            } else {
                console.log("no dato");
            }
        });
    });
}

const promesa = datoGrafico();
console.log(promesa); //pero aqui me devuelve una promesa pendiente

/* Aquí vamos a recibir el dato que resolvimos anteriormente */
promesa.then(resultado => {
    console.log(resultado);  //y aqui me devuelve undefined
});
```

Aquí un ejemplo de lo segundo:

```
/* Sigue siendo una función */
let datoGrafico = async function() {
    let {currentUser : user} = await firebase.auth();
    if (user != null) {
        var uid = user.uid;
    }
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    /* Devolvemos la promesa que se resolverá adelante */
    return db.collection("infoUsuarios").doc(uid);
}

const promesa = datoGrafico();
console.log(promesa); //pero aqui me devuelve una promesa pendiente

/* Aquí metemos el código que antes esperaste a que se resolviera */
promesa.then(docRef => {
    docRef.onSnapshot(doc => {
        if (doc && doc.exists) {
            let valor1 = doc.data().Peso;
            /* Aquí hacemos lo que deseemos con el valor */
            console.log(valor1); //aqui logro imprimir el valor que quiero
        } else {
            console.log("no dato");
        }
    });
});
```